# A Chaotik-Evil Encrypted Doppelblock

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

This is a birthday gift for my friend: Ivan a.k.a. **chaotic_iak**! ^^

As noted, you may need this clue if you want to solve this logically (otherwise, challenge yourself like Ivan):

> $\{I,A,K\} = \{0,0,0\}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution using the "logical starter".

> We're given the information $IAK=000$, so let's fill them in first.
> [image]

> There are a few characteristics to notice: we have exactly four vertical dominoes (possibly horizontally touching at the third row), and no clue can be 6, so there will be no rows/columns where 1st and 5th cell are shaded. Since each row must have two shaded cells, we have only two possibilities (plus their vertical mirror images):
> [image][image]

> But the former is impossible because the clue set 2, 3, 4, 5 can only have at most two single gaps. So we choose the latter, and the only single gap on row 4 becomes the 2.
> [image]

> Then, we know that, in either orientation (as-is or vertically flipped), C will have to clue a single gap (col 2) and a double gap (row 5) at the same time, so C must be 3. But the current orientation will fail at the later stage, since the top 2x2 square must have the sum of 9 (for the remaining clues 4 and 5), but we have 1, 2, 1, 3 to fill in there instead: 
> [image]

> So we retry with the vertical mirror image.
> [image]

> The 4 and 5 clues imply that the doubles must include a 3, so we can fill in the rest:
> [image]

> $CHAOTIK = 3502400$.

Comment: Correct and very well done! :D